# How does one completely roll back a Team Foundation Server workspace?

Tags: version-control, tfs

I sometimes forget to uncheck the "preserve local changes" box when creating a shelfset in Team Foundation. As a result, I have a working copy which has comments, changed files, associated work items, etc. which I would like to revert to the "pristine" state as if I had just checked it out.

The way I have been doing this up till now has been to create a separate shelfset where I did uncheck that box, and the immediately delete the shelfset. But this seems to be a major pain in the neck.

Is there a "undo everything" button that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. In Source Control Explorer, navigate to any parent that contains all your children (you could do this on $/, for instance) and right-click and select "Undo Pending Changes..." from the context menu.
2. In the Pending Changes View, select all the changes and right-click and select "Undo".

Both these should be functionally equivalent to undoing the pending changes when you shelve.

Comment: No, this does not undo work item associations, comments, etc. It only undoes file changes.

Comment: @BillyONeal: yeah, now I understand what you're trying to do.